# Can we create Security permission/access rights for each fields

Tags: openerp-7

I have users called Admin and Users.

I given all access rights for admin.

As i know we can give permissions for a table but not for particular fields.

Is it possible to give permissions/access rights for fields?

For Example: In table 'x' there are 2 fields called name and ph.num, we can create a group for table 'x' for Admin and give rights to edit name and ph.num. And i will create another group for same table 'x' for User that he can edit only ph.num. If i login as User he can change both name and ph.num, So my question is to edit only one ph.num field. How can we do this?